# How do I avoid test duplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This code appears in two of my specs:

```
it 'does not add the reply' do
  expect { subject }.not_to change { replies.length }
end

it 'does not publish the event' do
  expect { subject }.not_to publish_event(:reply_event)
end
```

How should I write my spec to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper like show in detail in the following blog

https://niallburkley.com/blog/rspecs-shared_examples_for/